# Build Error Jenkins : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, cucumber, selenium-grid

Im trying to build a project maven for automationg testiong the scenarios working fine when i excute them on local but when i try to build the job I got this error
[image]

i already added the chromedriver, the build is on a vm Linux i added the chromedriver for Lunix too

[image]

I downloaded the last version of chrome driver.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by following reasons,

1. In linux/vm we need to provide executable/higher permission on chrome driver.

> chmod 777 chromedriver

1. if you connecting to remote driver, we need to do port connectivity between machines.

Comment: i already added the command "chmod 777 /home/jenkins/workspace/'Build Mage TestAuto'/MAGEV3/Driver/chromedriver" in section "pre steps" and it gives me the same message error

Comment: how can i do port connectivity between machines ?

Comment: By default, jenkins will be in 8080 port, driver in 4444. try to connect to them.  
this link will be useful for you : https://netbeez.net/blog/telnet-to-test-connectivity-to-tcp/    ...  or ask any devops help on this.